# Hook in Podfile to edit my project file

Tags: cocoapods, xcodeproj

I want to fix Cocoapods bug, when it adds `Embed Pods Frameworks` build phase for Extension targets. These phases are not needed there.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4203

I wrote script to remove it

```
puts "Deleting not needed phases…"
project_path = "Keyboard.xcodeproj"
project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)
project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name.include?("Extension")
        phase = target.shell_script_build_phases.find { |bp| bp.name == 'Embed Pods Frameworks' }
        if !phase.nil?
            puts "Deleting Embed Pods Frameworks phase…"
            target.build_phases.delete(phase)
        end
    end
end

project.save
```

I can run this script after `pod install` manually, but I want to add it to Podfile somehow. It doesn't work in `post_install` hook

```
post_install do |installer|
    ...
end
```

because `UserProjectIntegrator.integrate!` is called after `post_install` and it overrides my changes.

Is there any way to integrate this script in Podfile?

Comment: It will be a nice idea to add this to the podfile. Any success on this?

Comment: @the.evangelist no :( and no news from github issue. I'm running ruby script manually after "pod install".

Comment: @pilot34, nice to meet you on the web =))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is No. 
The long answer: 
From the output of `pod install --verbose`, the build phase `Embed Pods Frameworks` is added in the `Integrating client project` which runs after the post_install step in the Podfile.
This is why you should execute this script separately after the pod install finished running.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the same issue by using the post_integrate hook

```
post_integrate do |installer|
   # your changes to the build phase
end
```